# Fixed height when panel is scrollable?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

the following code shows a definition of one of my views I'm using in my current app, that means this view is easily created and added to the *Ext.Viewport* when it should be displayed.

Its structure is quite easy: there's a toolbar with a panel underneath, which can contain any other components like buttons, panels etc.

But: my problem is, that since I added the config **scrollable: true** to the panel (as you can see below), I also have to set a fixed height for that panel (300 in this case). If I don't set a height, all components within the panel aren't displayed at all.

The even worse problem is, that I don't know **what** height I should set here, because my app should of course work on different devices with different screen-sizes (iPhone/iPad/...).

So what I want to achieve is that the panel under the toolbar uses the fully available height and - in case its contents are "higher" than its own height - it should be scrollable. Hope you can help me with that :-)

```
Ext.define('PV.view.Menu', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    xtype: 'menu',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'My Menu'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                scrollable: true,
                height: 300,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Navigate to view 1 >',
                        action: 'nav-to-view1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Navigate to view 2 >',
                        action: 'nav-to-view2'
                    },
                    {
                        html: 'A lot of text<br />A lot of text<br />A lot of text<br />A lot of text<br />A lot of text'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `layout:'fit'`, as well as (possibly) `minHeight`

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-minHeight

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.Fit

```
config: {
    layout:'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'My Menu'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            scrollable: true,
//                height: 300,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Navigate to view 1 >',
                    action: 'nav-to-view1'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Navigate to view 2 >',
                    action: 'nav-to-view2'
                },
                {
                    html: 'A lot of text<br />A lot of text<br />A lot of text<br />A lot of text<br />A lot of text'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! :-)
I tried out your suggestion with the `layout: fit`, but it didn't worked. You can see it in the example on senchafiddle.com that I created: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ouwAK. With `layout: fit` the whole layout seems broken :-(

Comment: And the definition of a minHeight doesn't really solve the problem of the different screen-sizes I think, does it?
I mean, when I define the minHeight to the iPhone's height, the panel is too **short** on iPad. And when I define the minHeight to the iPad's height, the panel is too **long** on iPhone :-(

Comment: I feel confused... The fiddle, with a dock added to the toolbar, and more text, is exactly what I understand you are looking for? http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ouwAK#PAOSf

Comment: Ouch, thank you very much! :-) The addition _with a dock added to the toolbar_ was very helpful ;-) And it did the trick!
I also found another solution by playing around with it: you also could use `layout: 'vbox'` and give the toolbar `flex: 0` and the panel `flex: 1` (see http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ouwAK#PAOSf#HrxKM) But your solution is cleaner and simpler I think, thanks for that!